# Possible Inaccuracy at classic paper by Bayer and Stillman

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In reading the paper [Bayer and Stillman, "A criterion for detecting $m$-regularity"](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN356556735_0087/PPN356556735_0087___LOG_0007.pdf), i believe i have encountered what may be a little inaccuracy, which i describe next.

Let $I$ be a homogeneous ideal of a polynomial ring of dimension $n$ over an infinite field and suppose that $\dim S/I = 0$. Then at the $(a \Rightarrow b)$ direction of the proof of Lemma 1.7, the authors claim that $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^i(I)=0$ for any $i \neq 1$. Now, i claim that by Grothendieck's vanishing theorem, and since the Krull dimension of $I$ is $r$, we must also have $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^n(I) \neq 0$. If that's right, then the argument given in the proof in the paper is imprecise. How serious is this?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759645/a-little-paradox-in-local-cohomology-of-zero-dimensional-ideals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $H^n_{\mathfrak m}(I)=H^n_{\mathfrak m}(S)\ne0$. But $\max\{i:H^n_{\mathfrak m}(S)_i≠0\}=−n$, so for $d≥−n+1$ we have $H^n_{\mathfrak m}(S)_d=0$. This shows that the same conclusion holds for $m≥0$ and $d≥m−n+1$. At this point I guess (but I'm not sure!) they assume $m≥0$ in this lemma (otherwise (c) is automatically satisfied).